# bootstrap nav bar doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap nav-bar in my css file, the code is below and the page should look like this:

[Expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZht2.jpg)

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="{{url_for('static',filename='c:/vms web/app/static/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel=stylesheet">
  </head>

 <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
 </header>
 </html>
```

however the page is like this:

[Actual layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsvU9.jpg)

any idea why?

Comment: Check _bootstrap.min.css_ if loaded correctly, i think your problem with it.

Comment: it seems good, i don't really know what's the issue :(

Comment: Your 'bootstrap.css' file isn't being loaded which is why none of the bootstrap styles are applied. Any reason for that fancy `<link>` element in stead of a more traditional one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check page source - what you have in `<link href=`.

There is similar as you use server side directives, but your web server don't processed it.

Comment: great, so the href in the view source was:{ static/c:/vms web/app/static/css/bootstrap.min.css } so i deleted {c:/vms web/app/static/} and it is working...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add bootstrap in your head but you do it wrong. Your head should be like this:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourhref">
</head>
```

On "yourhref" you have to put your link to the css file, but it seems you are using ruby and I don't know how to do it.

Remember to add the Js files too!

Comment: thank you :) ...you are right! but i still don't know why using url_for in head is wrong

Answer (score 0):

check your
 `<link href="{{url_for('static',filename='c:/vms web/app/static/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel=stylesheet">`

There is a space that might be breaking the connection.

You can use developer tools and see if you get any errors.